# Reading an .evtx file in Power Shell

Tags: c#, xml, powershell

I am trying to convert an event log file (.evtx) to xml using Power Shell (and later read this xml in a C# program). I am running the script

```
get-winevent -Path "C:\test.evtx" -oldest | convertto-xml -as Stream > "C:\test.xml"
```

but the resultant xml file has many events whose 'Message' field is EMPTY. If I open the same .evtx in Windows Event viewer, I can see messages of all events.

Though this problem is reported and people have talked about it ([here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverpowershell/thread/12467b47-c1e6-4208-bbbf-9fec9b4b8111) & [here](http://connectppe.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/716533/get-winevent-does-not-return-the-content-of-the-event-message-in-v3-ctp2)), I am unable to find a solution / workaround for this.

Can anyone please tell me if there is something new availlable on this issue or any information that might be helpful.

PS: I am using Power shell version 2.0.

Comment: You said `in Windows Event viewer, I can see messages of all events`... is there any special character (including comparison signs) in the messages that are missing in the XML?

Comment: @YannickBlondeau: Thanks for your comment. I can actually check if there are any special charecters in the messages, but I should say, the same event log is properly converted to XML (i.e. with no missing messages) on a different machine with 2008 R2 OS. Where as, on my Windows7 Machine, this issue is happening.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you forgot to mention the depth to which PowerShell should recurse into and create an XML representation of the Object, default value for depth is 1. Something like below should work

```
get-winevent -Path "C:\test.evtx" -oldest | convertto-xml -as Stream -depth 10 > "C:\test.xml"
```

Answer (score 1):

I noticed you said you wanted to read an eventlog in PS > xml to the process in C#.
I'm just reading the .evtx files in C# directly:

```
class Program
    {
        static IEnumerable<EventLogRecord> LogRecordCollection(string filename, string xpathquery = "*")
        {
            var eventLogQuery = new EventLogQuery(filename, PathType.FilePath, xpathquery);

        using (var eventLogReader = new EventLogReader(eventLogQuery))
        {
            EventLogRecord eventLogRecord;

            while ((eventLogRecord = (EventLogRecord)eventLogReader.ReadEvent()) != null)
                yield return eventLogRecord;
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var path = "file.evtx";
        var start = new DateTime(2013, 06, 26, 0, 0, 0);
        var end = new DateTime(2013, 06, 27, 0, 0, 0);
        var t = from l in LogRecordCollection(path)
               where l.TimeCreated > start
               && l.TimeCreated < end
               select l;
        foreach (var item in t)
        {
            var msg = item.Properties[0].Value.ToString();
            if (msg.Contains("[interesting key]"))
            {
                Console.Write(item.TimeCreated);
                Console.Write(";");
                Console.Write(item.TaskDisplayName);
                Console.Write(";");
                Console.Write(item.ProviderName);
                Console.Write(";");

                Console.Write(msg);
                Console.Write(";");
                Console.WriteLine();
            }

        }
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, tell me how it works. 
`$Objects = get-WinEvent -Maxevents 10 |ConverTo-XML -NoTypeInformation
$objects.Object|Select -ExpandProperty Property`

EDIT: Sorry I forgot about the whole 'wanting it in a file'...

$Objects = get-WinEvent -Maxevents 10 |ConverTo-XML -NoTypeInformation -as Stream > C:\Test.xml